# 10 SolrCore Initialization Failures ...can't get rid of them

Tags: mysql, apache, solr

I'n using the GUI via web of SOLR... and it sucks so bad that is not clear at all what to do: I click ADD CORE and all I got is an errors... i tried multiple times and all i get is more errore like

> new_core:
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
>   Could not load conf for core new_core: Error loading solr config from
>   /var/solr/data/new_core/conf/solrconfig.xml

how can i get rid of them?? should i reinstall SOLR from scratch? i can't get pass this point... and my goal will be to use mysql with it but is gonna take years at this point... so frustrating..

Answer (score 3):

to DELETE CORES, therefore the failures just use
YOURDOMAIN.COM:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=UNLOAD&core=[NAME OF THE CORE]